# Subdivision surface modifier adds crease to head

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

[image]

How do I fix this issue and have a nice smooth head?

file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iihG60xaokuOx3EAqDik2LGjbg8KCVxv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have double vertices on the same spot.

To merge all vertices on the same spot you have to select all vertices and press  <kbd>M</kbd> and select *Merge > By Distance*